# PHP generate image and failed with permission denied

Tags: php, image, permissions

My php is trying to re-generate a new image file by imagejpeg, this is my code as follow:

```
  $newFileName = getCurrentTimeStamp().'.jpg';
  $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadFileUrl);
  $newImage = imagejpeg($image, $newFileName, 80);
```

But I got error with this function as follow.

Warning: imagejpeg(): Unable to open '1373627954.jpg' for writing: Permission denied in /Users/x/Sites/xxxx/php/api_crop_photo.php on line 69 failed

I actually have already chmod the permission of the folder with read/write.

but still meet this problem, has anyone meet this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, hope it did not miss leading anyone.
Actually, my mistake was the $newFileName, I didn't give the correct file path.

Comment: Please check you folder permission too